# How to access index in vue.js for loop element?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In vue.js i have

```
                        <button v-bind:class="[mdc-tab, {index==currentTab : mdc-tab--active}]" role="tab" aria-selected="true" v-for="(tab,index) in tabs.data" v-bind:key="tab.id">
                            <span class="mdc-tab__content">
                                <span class="mdc-tab__icon material-icons" aria-hidden="true">{{tab.icon}}</span>
                                <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">{{tab.name}}</span>
                            </span>
                            <span v-bind:class="[mdc-tab-indicator, {index==$root.currentTab : mdc-tab-indicator--active}]">
                                <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
                        </button>
```

index is the current index of the loop. currentTab comes from

```
            tabs : {
                currentTab : 0,
                data : [
                    {icon:'title',name:'Name'},
                    {icon:'style',name:'Tags'},
                    {icon:'info',name:'Status'},
                    {icon:'warning',name:'Restriction'},
                    {icon:'keyboard_arrow_right',name:'Other'}
                ]
            }
```

I get this error

```
- invalid expression: Unexpected token == in

    [mdc-tab, {index==currentTab : mdc-tab--active}]

  Raw expression: v-bind:class="[mdc-tab, {index==currentTab : mdc-tab--active}]"
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the opposite, i.e. the class name as the key and condition as the value:

```
v-bind:class="['mdc-tab', { 'mdc-tab--active': index === tabs.currentTab }]"
```

Same for the indicator:

```
v-bind:class="['mdc-tab-indicator', { 'mdc-tab-indicator--active': index === tabs.currentTab }]"
```

Comment: how can I access currentTab from inside?

Comment: If `tabs` is a property in your data, then you can directly access it with `tabs.currentTab`. @omega

Comment: How can I change it from `v-bind:class` to `v-bind:once`? putting v-once doesn't work

Comment: it's because the mdc framework already changes the class itself, so I don't want to bind it again with vue.